# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" Error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have this code here. I keep getting an error:
Cannot convert undefined or null to object (or sometimes TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.)

Here is my code

```
const AdresList = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getXAddress()
      .then((response) => {
        const { data } = response || {};
        setData(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <DashboardLayout>
      {isLoading && (
        <TableRow sx={{ my: "1rem", padding: "6px 18px" }}>
          <Typography whiteSpace="pre" m={0.75} textAlign="left">
            <Skeleton variant="text" />
          </Typography>
          <Typography flex="1 1 260px !important" m={0.75} textAlign="left">
            <Skeleton variant="text" />
          </Typography>

          <Typography whiteSpace="pre" textAlign="right" color="grey.600">
            <Skeleton variant="text" />
          </Typography>
        </TableRow>
      )}

      {data?.length > 0 &&
        data.map((row) => (
          <TableRow sx={{ my: "1rem", padding: "6px 18px" }} key={row.id}>
            <Typography whiteSpace="pre" m={0.75} textAlign="left">
              {row.attributes.name}
            </Typography>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
};

export default AdresList;
```

And the code of function

```
export const getXAddress = async () => {
  const response = await apiClient.get("/adress");
  return response.data;
};
```

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: are you sure `data?.length > 0` is what you have in your condition ? because it returns `false` when `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: Ok I deleted this but I've got the error that "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Answer (score 0):

There are a little issue in your code.

I saw that when the `useEfect` make a request, you are handling the response in a wrong way when do this `const { data } = response || {};`

So if `response` is undefined the code gives `{}` (empty object). And next, when this part: `setData(data);` was runned, your array is replaced by undefined, resulting in problems like:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Do this:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getXAddress()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

Look that I move your `setIsLoading(false)` to `finally`, because if your `Promise` dispatch a `catch()` isLoading will be still true.

And the last. Watch out with your `getXAddress` function. Make sure that `data` will pass away or will be returned only the value. Otherwise will result in:

> Cannot read data from undefined

```
export const getXAddress = async () => {
  const response = await apiClient.get("/adress");
  //Do this if you want to use de "response.data" at "then()"
  return response;
  //Or this if you want to use only "response" as result at "then()"
  return response.data;
};
```

Comment: I corretemd function useEffect as you mentioned but right now I've got the error Cannot convert undefined or null to object. In function getXAddress I used response.data

Comment: Add to your question the full error with the stack. Maybe now the problem isn't the code you are showing us.

Comment: The stack is like

```
Error: ...........
at .....
at .....
at ......
```